# HTTPForbidden context route not firing

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid

I'm having a bit of trouble getting security in Pyramid to work properly. My security itself seems to be working: if a user attempts to access a resource they are not authorized to view, Pyramid throws an `HTTPForbidden` exception. The problem is that in this instance, it's supposed to fall back to the login view, which isn't happening. I'm just getting the default Pyramid exception screen with the stacktrace.

my login view:

```
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPForbidden

@view_config(context = HTTPForbidden, renderer="login.mak")
@view_config(route_name = 'login', renderer='login.mak')
class Login(ViewBase):
    def __init__(self, request):
        super(Login, self).__init__(request)
        self.data['title'] = "Login"

        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.params['username']
            passwd = request.params['password']
            validuser = User.check(name, passwd)
            if validuser is None:
                self.data['requested_path'] = request.params['requestpath']
                self.__call__()
            else:
                headers = remember(request, str(validuser.id))
                raise HTTPFound(
                    location = request.params['requestpath'],
                    headers = headers
                    )
        else:
            self.data['requested_path'] = request.url

    def __call__(self):
        return self.data
```

All of views have a default permission set to 'view', my `acl` class looks as follows:

```
from pyramid.security import Allow
from pyramid.security import Everyone
from pyramid.security import Authenticated
from pyramid.security import ALL_PERMISSIONS

# Handles ACL auth for the entire application

class RootFactory(object):

    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
        (Allow, 'Editor', 'edit'),
        (Allow, 'Admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS)
    ]

    def __init__(self, request):
        pass

def groupfinder(userid, request):

    from ctic.models import User

    user = User.get(userid)
    member_groups = []
    if user != None:
        member_groups.append(user.group.groupname)
        return member_groups
    else:
        return None
```

As I said, the ACL aspect appears to be working.

Interestingly, if I remove the default_permission from my `init.py`, everything works as normal.

Any pointers as to where im going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unrelated to your problem, but the way a class-based view works in Pyramid is that it's a 2-step process. 1) Pyramid instantiates your class with the `request` object 2) Pyramid calls either the `__call__` method or a method specified by `attr` in `view_config`. Thus, the call to `self.__call__()` in your `__init__` is incorrect.

The way you're using class-based views is a little unconventional, but I don't see any actual bugs in what you've pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupfinder()` should return a list in all cases.  If the user isn't in any groups, return `[]` instead of `None`.

I'm not sure if this is your problem.  But I experienced similar behaviour when I returned `None` instead of `[]`.

Comment: "in all cases" is incorrect. A groupfinder has 2 purposes: 1) determine if a user is authenticated - this is done by returning None if the user is not logged in, or a list if they are 2) determine what principals a user has - this means populating the returned list with principals that are matched against the ACLs in your system. The groupfinder in his example does this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add "permission=NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED" to your view_config

```
from pyramid.security import NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED
@view_config(context = HTTPForbidden, renderer="login.mak", permission=NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED)
```